# Heroku deploy results in "Multipack app" timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku, but every time it results in this error after hanging for over 15 mins.

```
       AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer

 !     Timed out compiling Multipack app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

To git@heroku.com:examplesite.git
 ! [remote rejected] refs/heroku_san/deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:examplesite.git'
git update-ref -d refs/heroku_san/deploy
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [git push git@heroku.com:examplesite...]
```

I am using heroku_san, but the same error occurs when I do `git push heroku master`. Any help would be much appreciated! I am running rails 3.2

Comment: We don't have know anything about your application so it is hard to help, but is it possible that you have a lot of gems that require native extensions, or you have a bunch of assets that are getting compiled?

Comment: Hi Justin, yes there are a relatively large amount of gems and assets

Comment: You could try compiling the assets on your machine and add them to the repo, so that Heroku won't need to compile them for you. It could speed things up.

Comment: I am doing that at the moment actually. It is taking a while, which I am assuming means this was what was timing it out. Will let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem, which ensured I wasn't precompiling assets more than once, as well as caching them so subsequent precompiles would only precompile files that have changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your .buildpacks file, make sure the repos you're pointing to are https and not http.  Saw the answer here https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/issues/16 .

Answer (score 0):

You should cache your assets in memcached to speed up your deploy.

You can dramatically speed up your asset compilation time and overall deploy time if you cache your compiled assets.  If you have a memcached service or add one, it's easy to add a small asset caching layer.  This will write the generated assets into the cache and only compile the assets changed since the last deploy in each new deploy.  Assets that haven't changed will be pulled from the cache as is.

At a high level you will need to:

- Add a Heroku memcached addon
- Configure memcached client gems (like dalli)
- Set asset pipeline asset cache in memcached

Full details in this blog post describing using memcached for Heroku asset caching: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/faster-deploys